# Identify this card game, where you have to beat previous cards put on the table

Tags: identify-this-game

I remember playing this card game using a regular card deck but I don't remember the exact rules and also don't know what it's called. If it helps, I live in the Netherlands so it might not be known anywhere else. If the Dutch name of the game is known that would also be great.

This is what I remember.

- I think it must be played with at least 3 people, but the more the better I think.
- Everyone is dealt an amount of cards. (I don't remember what amount)
- The player whose turn it is lays down a card. Or multiple cards with the same rank.
- The next player should then put a higher card on the table and when there are multiple cards he should put the same number of cards that are all of the same rank and of course higher.
- At any time before the next player responds to some cards any other player may throw in a card of the same rank to make it harder for the player to beat it.
- I can't remember what exactly happens if you can't beat it. But I believe that it just meant that the player that won is able to lay down the next card(s) on the table to start a new chain.
- I also don't remember what the exact goal of the game was and when (if even) a player could draw new cards.
- I also believe the terms "attack" were used but I'm not 100% sure

Example with 4 players (as I remember it):

1. player one lays down a 7.
2. player two lays down a 8.
3. before player three responds player one throws in another 8
4. player three lays down two 10s. (to be able to beat two 8s)
5. and so on

I can also imagine this is a game that has multiple rules variations. If anyone knows what this game is called and what the exact rules are , that would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called President and goes by many different other names, most of which are better not mentioned here. A rule you forgot to mention is that the winning player(s) from last round get the best cards of the loosing player(s).

[Here you can find all the details](http://www.pagat.com/climbing/president.html) with many variants

Comment: Definitely is the game I'm looking for. The intercepting by other players must have been a custom rule

Comment: See also The Great Dalmuti, a version played with a special deck.

Answer (score 1):

There's a similar game in Japan that goes by the name *daifugo*.

The two main differences versus your description are that

1. people cannot jump in randomly (proceeds clockwise unless people pass because they cannot play).
2. playing four cards of a kind causes a reversal of the winning hands (from 3 up to A, 2 becomes from 2, A up to 3).

Separately, there are lots of variants. 
In *daifugo*, 8s often have a special meaning of leading to a stop.